# Google Apps Script - Change authorization account

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Scripts may run on behalf of a selected account [granting access to resources](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization).

Once development is done, what steps are required to allow running the script on behalf of another user account?

Comment: You could create an addon or you could install the script into other account or you could put it in a library.

Comment: By installing the script in another account means taking ownership of the document (spreadsheet, form, etc) from another account and running the script from there? This will change the account granting authorisation?